# (C++) My overloaded operator functions are all returning the error that they must be unary or binary despite being friends

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, binary-operators

My fraction classes overloaded operators won't compile, saying they must be a unary or binary operator. (c++)
After searching around, i found the advice that making them friends would remove the implicit first term, but my operators have been friends this entire time and still return " error: overloaded 'operator-' must be a unary or binary
      operator (has 3 parameters)" when i go to compile.

Here they are in my header file

```
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fraction& frac); //printing
friend std::istream& operator>>( std::istream& is, Fraction& frac); // reading
friend const Fraction operator+(const Fraction& x, const Fraction& y); // adding
friend const Fraction operator-(const Fraction& x, const Fraction& y); // subtract
```

and here are the definitions for each of those

```
std::ostream& Fraction::operator<<(std::ostream& os, const Fraction& frac) //printing
{
    if(num % den == 0)
        cout << num/den << endl;
    else
        cout << num << "/" << den << endl;
}

std::istream& Fraction::operator>>( std::istream& is, Fraction& frac) // reading
{
    int pc; //peek character

    is >> skipws >> num; // read numerator, skipping whitespace

    pc = is.peek(); // check next character

    if( is && isspace(pc))  //if whitespace after the numerator
    {
        while( is && isspace(pc))
        {
            is.get(); // eat space
            pc = is.peek(); // move through the stream
        }
    }
    else if( is && pc == '/')
    {
        is.get(); // eat the '/'
        is >> skipws >> den;
    }

    if(den == 0)
    {
        throw invalid_argument("denominator is zero");
    }

    if(den < 0)
    {
        num = num * -1;
        den = den * -1;
    }
}

const Fraction Fraction::operator+(const Fraction& x, const Fraction& y) // adding
{
    Fraction temp1;
    Fraction temp2;
    if(x.getden() == y.getden())
    {
        temp1.set(x.getnum() + y.getnum(), x.getden() );
    }
    else
    {
        temp1.set(x.getnum() * y.getden(), x.getden() * y.getden());
        temp2.set(y.getnum() * x.getden(), y.getden() * x.getden());
        temp1.set(temp1.getnum() + temp2.getnum(), temp1.getden());
    }
    reduceFrac(temp1);
    return temp1;
}

const Fraction Fraction::operator-(const Fraction& x, const Fraction& y) // subtracting
{
    Fraction temp1;
    Fraction temp2;
    if(x.getden() == y.getden())
    {
        temp1.set(x.getnum() - y.getnum(), x.getden() );
    }
    else
    {
        temp1.set(x.getnum() * y.getden(), x.getden() * y.getden());
        temp2.set(y.getnum() * x.getden(), y.getden() * x.getden());
        temp1.set(temp1.getnum() - temp2.getnum(), temp1.getden());
    }
    reduceFrac(temp1);
    return temp1;

}
```

Comment: Why are these all members of `Fraction`?

Comment: aren't friend functions not members of the class?

Comment: Members of the class don't need friendship to access private stuff.

Comment: `Fraction::operator<<` -> `operator<<`, for one thing.

Comment: [cppreference's article on operator overloading is relevant here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators). It might clear some things up.

Comment: When you are overloading a binary operator as a member function, you pass only the second value as an parameter. `this` plays the role of the first value. Unary operator doesn't have parameters at all.

Answer (score 0):

Friend functions aren't instance members of a class. They are static, and members of other classes, or no class.

Making them friends won't 'remove the implicit first term', whatever that means. Making them *instance members* removes the *explicit* first term (by making it implicit: `this`), which is your actual problem: they are members and they have an explicit first term. Either make them static or remove `friend` and the first terms.

Making members friends of their own class is redundant.

Comment: Thanks, I've got the +- now, that was really helpful. However, i still don't really understand why i'd remove the first term on the  insertion/extraction operators. can i actually remove the stream from each of their declarations safely (while editing the definition to fit this)? Edit: after attempting to remove the ostream it now tells me it only has one parameter and must be a binary operator - not sure what i did

Comment: If it's an instance member, the implicit first operand is `this`. Static functions don't have `this`, so you have to explicitly supply the first operand. I don't understand your final question, or what you did to provoke the error. Either make the binary operator functions instance members with one argument, or static functions with two. Unary operator functions should have zero or one argument respectively.